# NSJSONSerialization Not Working, NSUTF8StringEncoding Is Working

Tags: ios, json, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I've read the documentation, tutorials, and other Stack Q&A and am hung up on how I'm able to get my `JSON` to appear using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, but not using `NSJSONSerialization` - which is what I need to extract the data to a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`.  I believe it is an issue with the format of the `NSData` being returned from my URL?

*EDIT* Here is error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x8aabc30

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sampleURL.com"]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:15.0];

NSMutableData* responseData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    //this works, and have NSLog below
    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"string %@", responseString);

    [responseData appendData:data];
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];

     //this is null in NSLog
    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSLog(@"jsonDict dict %@",jsonDict); 
}
```

Debug Console:

```
 2014-03-11 07:41:58.233 WBPC[7845:a0b] string   {"id":"a1","session":"General","name":"Exhibitor Setup Begins","startTime":"0900","details":"9am Exhibitor Hall","png":"image","speaker1":"Johnson","speaker2":"Nelson","speaker3":""}{"id":"b1","session":"General","name":"Conference Registration","startTime":"1000","details":"10am Noon Upper Level Lobby","png":"image","speaker1":"Jackson","speaker2":"","speaker3":""}
 2014-03-11 07:41:58.236 WBPC[7845:a0b] jsonDict (null)
```

Comment: NSMutableDictionary  * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error]; Try this one

Comment: I actually tried that one (from one of you other Stack posts), and no luck.  I'm convinced it's a format issue of the JSON being returned from URL...

Comment: @NamoNamo - here is the error I receive from the NSJSONSerialization: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x8aabc30.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is not well formed. You tell us that it is (white space and line breaks added for legibility purposes):

```
{
    "id": "a1",
    "session": "General",
    "name": "Exhibitor Setup Begins",
    "startTime": "0900",
    "details": "9am Exhibitor Hall",
    "png": "image",
    "speaker1": "Johnson",
    "speaker2": "Nelson",
    "speaker3": ""
}{
    "id": "b1",
    "session": "General",
    "name": "Conference Registration",
    "startTime": "1000",
    "details": "10am Noon Upper Level Lobby",
    "png": "image",
    "speaker1": "Jackson",
    "speaker2": "",
    "speaker3": ""
}
```

That's missing a comma between the two dictionary entries, and you're missing the `[` and `]` that should wrap the JSON. If it's really an array of dictionary entries, it should be:

```
[
    {
        "id": "a1",
        "session": "General",
        "name": "Exhibitor Setup Begins",
        "startTime": "0900",
        "details": "9am Exhibitor Hall",
        "png": "image",
        "speaker1": "Johnson",
        "speaker2": "Nelson",
        "speaker3": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "b1",
        "session": "General",
        "name": "Conference Registration",
        "startTime": "1000",
        "details": "10am Noon Upper Level Lobby",
        "png": "image",
        "speaker1": "Jackson",
        "speaker2": "",
        "speaker3": ""
    }
]
```

If you want to check your JSON, you can visit http://jsonlint.com. Also, if you checked the `error` object returned by `JSONObjectWithData`, it would have pointed you in the right direction.

You should look how this JSON was generated. It looks like it must have been manually generated. If you were generating this from a PHP page, for example, you should use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/json_encode), for example, rather than manually generating the JSON.

---

By the way, you are trying to parse the result in `didReceiveData`. You shouldn't try to parse until `connectionDidFinishLoading`. Your `didReceiveData` should merely append the `data` to your `NSMutableData` object. The parsing should be deferred until `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

Comment: The issue was in how my PHP was outputting the JSON, I need to wrap it in an array like this: 
$output = array();

while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $output[] = $list;
}

echo json_encode($output);

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it all in the 'didReceiveData' delegate function which isn't the correct place. The only thing that should be there is:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}
```

but before this, you should initialise the 'self.responseData' when the connection receives a response:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if(self.responseData != nil) self.responseData = nil;
    self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}
```

and then, you need to implement another delegate function called 'connectionDidFinishLoading' and when this method is called, your 'responseData' will contain all of the data from the JSON and will be ready to parse:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

     responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSLog(@"string %@", responseString);

     NSError * error;
     NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

     NSLog(@"jsonDict dict %@",jsonDict); 
}
```

I hope that helps in some way.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  I actually do use these delegate methods I just simplified my example for illustration purposes.

Comment: In addition to that already shown above, in the delegate method `connection: didReceiveResponse:` one should check the HTTP status code and the kind of the response data (MIME type). If the status code indicates an error, we should read the response anyway in order to obtain a possible "error message" from the server. In `connectionDidFinishLoading:` we again take the HTTP status code to decide whether we should log an error message or process the expected response data according the MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this one.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: YOURDATA options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

if (!jsonResponseArray) {
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
} else {
   for(NSDictionary *dic in jsonResponseArray) {
      NSLog(@"dic values are : %@", item);
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this one as well and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string you have posted is not valid JSON. Just because the data is a valid UTF8 string doesn't mean it is necessarily JSON. Try pasting the string from your debugged into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it will show you that you're missing a comma between your JSON objects.

Comment: And of course JSON could be UTF-16 or UTF-32, so valid JSON doesn't need to be a valid UTF8 string.