# How to return a valid JSON object?

Tags: php, json

I'm just getting into php and I have an issue with the return of a JSON object.

Here's the code:

```
$stmt->bind_result($image_link, $start_time, $end_time, $viet_performer, $english_performer, $viet_event, $english_event, $day, $stage);

            while($stmt->fetch())
            {
                echo json_encode([["image_link" => $image_link,"start_time" => $start_time, "end_time" => $end_time, "viet_performer" => $viet_performer,
                                "english_performer" => $english_performer, "viet_event" => $viet_event, "english_event" => $english_event, "day" => $day,
                                "stage" => $stage]]);

                $stmt->bind_result($image_link, $start_time, $end_time, $viet_performer, $english_performer, $viet_event, $english_event, $day, $stage);
            }
```

This basically outputs:

> {"image_link":"schedule_music.jpg","start_time":"17:00","end_time":"18:30","viet_performer":"","english_performer":"","viet_event":"","english_event":"Tet
>   Music","day":0,"stage":1}
>   {"image_link":"schedule_music.jpg","start_time":"11:00","end_time":"12:00","viet_performer":"","english_performer":"","viet_event":"Nh?c","english_event":"Music","day":1,"stage":0}
>
> //repeat again

However, according to a JSON validator, it's an invalid JSON object.

I would like to produce a valid JSON like so:

> [{"image_link":"schedule_music.jpg","start_time":"17:00","end_time":"18:30","viet_performer":"","english_performer":"","viet_event":"","english_event":"Tet
>   Music","day":0,"stage":1},{"image_link":"schedule_music.jpg","start_time":"11:00","end_time":"12:00","viet_performer":"","english_performer":"","viet_event":"Nh?c","english_event":"Music","day":1,"stage":0}]

Notice the start/end brackets as well as a comma separator.

How can I achieve this?

Here is a better example (found somewhere) of how my output similarly looks like:

```
{
    "id": "a1",
    "session": "General",
    "name": "Exhibitor Setup Begins",
    "startTime": "0900",
    "details": "9am Exhibitor Hall",
    "png": "image",
    "speaker1": "Johnson",
    "speaker2": "Nelson",
    "speaker3": ""
}{
    "id": "b1",
    "session": "General",
    "name": "Conference Registration",
    "startTime": "1000",
    "details": "10am Noon Upper Level Lobby",
    "png": "image",
    "speaker1": "Jackson",
    "speaker2": "",
    "speaker3": ""
}
```

And how I would like to have the output look like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "a1",
        "session": "General",
        "name": "Exhibitor Setup Begins",
        "startTime": "0900",
        "details": "9am Exhibitor Hall",
        "png": "image",
        "speaker1": "Johnson",
        "speaker2": "Nelson",
        "speaker3": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "b1",
        "session": "General",
        "name": "Conference Registration",
        "startTime": "1000",
        "details": "10am Noon Upper Level Lobby",
        "png": "image",
        "speaker1": "Jackson",
        "speaker2": "",
        "speaker3": ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your updated code, the problem is that you are encoding each piece separately rather than encoding all of the data at once. Try this:

```
$stmt->bind_result($image_link, $start_time, $end_time, $viet_performer, $english_performer, $viet_event,
    $english_event, $day, $stage);

$data = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[] = [
        "image_link"        => $image_link,
        "start_time"        => $start_time,
        "end_time"          => $end_time,
        "viet_performer"    => $viet_performer,
        "english_performer" => $english_performer,
        "viet_event"        => $viet_event,
        "english_event"     => $english_event,
        "day"               => $day,
        "stage"             => $stage
    ];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

---

*Response based on earlier version of the question:*

It looks like you want an array of objects:

```
echo json_encode([
    [
        "image_link"        => $image_link,
        "start_time"        => $start_time,
        "end_time"          => $end_time,
        "viet_performer"    => $viet_performer,
        "english_performer" => $english_performer,
        "viet_event"        => $viet_event,
        "english_event"     => $english_event,
        "day"               => $day,
        "stage"             => $stage
    ]
]);
```

Note that an array containing string keys is going to be converted to an object by `json_encode`. In the above code, the inner array becomes an object while the outer array does not.

---

This may be a more intuitive way to look at it:

```
$objectOne = (object) [
    "image_link"        => $image_link,
    "start_time"        => $start_time,
    "end_time"          => $end_time,
    "viet_performer"    => $viet_performer,
    "english_performer" => $english_performer,
    "viet_event"        => $viet_event,
    "english_event"     => $english_event,
    "day"               => $day,
    "stage"             => $stage
];

$objectTwo = (object) [
    "image_link"        => $image_link,
    "start_time"        => $start_time,
    "end_time"          => $end_time,
    "viet_performer"    => $viet_performer,
    "english_performer" => $english_performer,
    "viet_event"        => $viet_event,
    "english_event"     => $english_event,
    "day"               => $day,
    "stage"             => $stage
];

echo json_encode([$objectOne, $objectTwo]);
```

Comment: This does not produce the result I need. This will wrap every json object into one array, like so `[{"image_link":"schedule_huong_sy_nhan.jpg","start_time":"13:30","end_time":"14:00","viet_performer":"","english_performer":"Huong Sy Nhan","viet_event":"","english_event":"Singing","day":2,"stage":0}][{"image_link":"schedule_unknown.png","start_time":"21:00","end_time":"","viet_performer":"","english_performer":"","viet_event":"","english_event":"End of Festival","day":2,"stage":1}]`. Notice the brackets. However, I would like it to be like in the expected output....unless I'm not understanding.

Comment: If it helps, I would like it to be as shown in the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326273/nsjsonserialization-not-working-nsutf8stringencoding-is-working

Comment: @Pangu Unless I'm missing something, I still think this is the solution you're looking for. I added an additional example to clarify.

Comment: this is what I added: `echo json_encode([["image_link" => $image_link,"start_time" => $start_time, "end_time" => $end_time, "viet_performer" => $viet_performer,"english_performer" => $english_performer, "viet_event" => $viet_event, "english_event" => $english_event, "day" => $day,"stage" => $stage]]);` However, this does not produce the same output as the clearer example I provided.

Comment: @Pangu The output you expect contains two objects. You are only passing one. See my second example.

Comment: Yep you are getting valid JSON it's just an array not an object. Therefore you need to parse an object into JSON as shown in this answer

Comment: mtinsley: you are correct, I have updated my code in description. Maybe that will help you?..I have a loop that outputs each json, and I guess that's where the issue is maybe?

Comment: @mtinsley please join me in a chat room to discuss

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to generate the data structure first, **then** encode it:

```
$foo = [];
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $foo []= [
         "image_link" => $image_link,
         "start_time" => $start_time,
         "end_time" => $end_time,
         "viet_performer" => $viet_performer,
         "english_performer" => $english_performer,
         "viet_event" => $viet_event,
         "english_event" => $english_event,
         "day" => $day,
         "stage" => $stage];
    ];
}
$json = json_encode($foo);
```